# Adding Android 4.x support with AsyncTask to JSON parser

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have such `JSONparser` class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and such activity:

```
public class BankExchangersListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity  {

    private static String url;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_Exchangers = "bank_exchangers";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_address = "address";
    private static final String TAG_location_name = "location_name";
    private static final String TAG_latitude = "latitude";
    private static final String TAG_longitude = "longitude";
    private static final String TAG_exchanger_type_name = "exchanger_type_name";
    private static final String TAG_exchanger_curr_value = "value";
    private static final String TAG_currency_list_name = "currency_list_name";
    private static final String TAG_direction_of_exchange_name = "direction_of_exchange_name";

    JSONArray banks = null;
    JSONArray exc_currencies = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String bank;
        bank = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("Bank_id");
        url = "****/**_**_***_list/"+bank+".json";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bank_exchangers_list);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            banks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Exchangers);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < banks.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = banks.getJSONObject(i);
                exc_currencies = c.getJSONArray("currency_values");
                HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
                for(int k = 0; k < exc_currencies.length(); k++){
                    JSONObject m = exc_currencies.getJSONObject(k);
                    String currency = m.getString(TAG_exchanger_curr_value); 
                    String currency_list_name = m.getString(TAG_currency_list_name); 
                    String direction_of_exchange_name = m.getString(TAG_direction_of_exchange_name); 
                    Log.e("wazzzup", currency); //here is trouble: how to do new array with linking to parent?
                    HashMap child = new HashMap();
                    child.put(TAG_exchanger_curr_value, currency );
                    child.put(TAG_currency_list_name, currency_list_name );
                    child.put(TAG_direction_of_exchange_name, direction_of_exchange_name );
                    secList.add(child);
                }
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                Log.e("name", name); //here is trouble: how to do new array with linking to parent?
                String address = c.getString(TAG_address);
                String location_name = c.getString(TAG_location_name);
                String latitude = c.getString(TAG_latitude);
                String longitude = c.getString(TAG_longitude);
                String exchanger_type_name = c.getString(TAG_exchanger_type_name);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_address, address);
                map.put(TAG_location_name, location_name);
                map.put(TAG_latitude, latitude);
                map.put(TAG_longitude, longitude);
                map.put(TAG_exchanger_type_name, exchanger_type_name);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
                result.add(secList);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.bank_exchanger_list_element,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_location_name, TAG_address, TAG_exchanger_type_name, TAG_latitude, TAG_longitude }, new int[] {
                        R.id.bank_e_n, R.id.nas_punkt_e_n , R.id.adress_obm_e_n , R.id.tip_obm_e_n , R.id.shirota_e_n , R.id.dolgota_e_n });

        setListAdapter(adapter);*/

                SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
                        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                                this,
                                contactList,              
                                R.layout.bank_exchanger_list_element,             
                                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_location_name, TAG_address, TAG_exchanger_type_name, TAG_latitude, TAG_longitude },
                                new int[] {
                                        R.id.bank_e_n, R.id.nas_punkt_e_n , R.id.adress_obm_e_n , R.id.tip_obm_e_n , R.id.shirota_e_n , R.id.dolgota_e_n },   
                                result,              //something goes here
                                R.layout.exchanger_currencies,             
                                new String[] {TAG_exchanger_curr_value, TAG_currency_list_name, TAG_direction_of_exchange_name},      
                                new int[] { R.id.currencyvalue_e_n, R.id.currency_list_name_e_n, R.id.direction_of_exchange_e_n}    
                            );
                        setListAdapter( expListAdapter ); 
                        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) getExpandableListView();
                        for(int i=0; i < expListAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
                            elv.expandGroup(i);

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bank_exchangers_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

On android 2.3.3 it works properly. But on 4.x i see errors, after searching I understood that I need to use `AsyncTask`. Is it true?

But how do I use it here? If there are any useful examples, please let me know.

Just how to get it working on Android 4.x?

Comment: In ICS you can't do network operations on the UI thread.  Using an ASyncTask is the right way to do it.

Comment: @marcantonio hm, could you explain it on code example?

Comment: read this page : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @forgivegod man i read this, but it's to complicated there, and to few examples on my case///

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should already use AsyncTask under Android 2.x. It greatly improves responsiveness. Here is a fragment from my MEGA API library (currently under development):

```
    private class AsyncRequestConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final Request request;

    public AsyncRequestConnection(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpPost p = createRequestHttpMessage(request);
            String resp = new String(stripResponse(getRequestClient().execute(p)));
            Log.v(TAG, resp);
            return resp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot complete API request", e);
            cancel(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        request.backoff();
        if (request.hasReachedMaxBackoff()) {
            request.cancel(R.string.error_internal);
        } else {
            requestQueue.enqueue(request);              
        }
        requestConnection = null;
        nextRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            request.attachResponse(result);
            request.handleResponse();               
            requestConnection = null;
            nextRequest();
        } else {
            request.cancel(R.string.error_internal);
        }
    }
}
```

`doInBackgroud()` is the only method that is run on a different thread. Here, all your costly operations should happen.
`getRequestClient()` returns a `HttpClient` (`AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(AGENT_NAME)` or reused object for multiple requests in a row).
Since you are running muliple threads here, make sure `doInBackground()` does not access any global data structure. In my example, get `getRequestClient()` is sure to be only called from this location and there is only one such AsyncTask at any time. Otherwise you need some kind of mutex. Also, the `Request` object is sure to used by this class exlusively. Event handling (call-back methods) is implemented in the `Request` object as well but for simpler tasks you could simply do everything you want to do in `onCancel()` and `onPostExecute()`.
If you only want to download a JSON object and parse it, you probably won't even need a constructor and private member variables. Simply replace the first `Void` by `String` to pass the URL string to `doInBackground()` and replace `String` by JSONObject.

Comment: what i need to put in doInBackground? and you mean change void to string of onCreate?

Comment: You must put the httpClient.execute into doInBackgroud() when using Android 4. You should do the same for Android 2 (or risk an ANR). You should do the parsing there as well because it might take some time and you are running a thread anyways (why not use it).

extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>

tells the compiler what parameter types and return types to use. The first type is what is given to doInBackground. The second type is for stating your current progress (cf. AsyncTask doc). The final type is the return type of doInBackground and the parameter for onPostExecute where result goes.

Comment: didn't try yet.... but accept...   Also how to be with my view adapter's? where to put them?

Comment: I prefer to put adapters into separate class files. Usually, I extend ArrayAdapter and overwrite getView and other methods as needed. What's tricky is then where to put on[Something]Listeners. That greatly depends on the individual case.